# Receptacle size for Stand up freezer

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a stand up freezer with 21 start up amps and 2 running amps.  Would a 20 amp breaker be sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don’t go by start up amps we go by what is called FLA full load amperage the 21 amps is locked rotor current, when motors start they draw 3-5 times the normal running value, that’s ok because it is usually less than 1 second so no heat has time to build up.
If the unit came with a plug that is the normal 2 parallel and a ground or the standard 15 amp 120v plug you can use a 15 amp circuit. If it is 1 blade rotated 90 degrees 120v it is a 20 amp plug and needs a 20 amp circuit.

Code has exceptions for motor circuits that require higher starting currents than normal the limit is 225%  NEC 440.22.

So there are exceptions and we work with the information on the nameplate. It will usually recommend a circuit size of 15 amps with a maximum of 10 amps.

Who wait you said the starting current was 21 amps! Well the circuit breaker is an inverse time device the higher the current the faster it trips. A 15 amp circuit will normally hold at 50 amps for a half second (you only need 21). So the amperage peak is very short and your current is already on its way back to FLA or 2 amps.

Putting a plug in device like this on a 30 amp circuit would be a code violation. And I would bet it will be fine on a 15 amp circuit.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I thought this might be the case but I’m still learning and wanted to double check. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

NEMA standard thermal magnetic circuit breakers trip on an inverse time curves that allow 5x the rating for about 4 seconds and 2x the rated current could hold for 30 seconds or more.

A 15A breaker should be adequate, but check with the installation instructions, they are part of the NRTL (UL,CSA,ETL) *Listing*, and supersede codes.

Comment: Actually you have to look at the trip curves, for example a square d QO at 4 seconds is around 2.5x the rated current all the breaker manufacturers are different this locks you into their brand to have a fully Coordinated system for larger systems. Most motors start in under a second that same curve is good for 7x at 1 second.  The curves are available at the manufactures web site

Comment: You're right ED, I need to throw in more indifinites like could, should, might or about..I was looking at a chart that claims to represent a NEMA Standard, my bookmark for the source is broken https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/167883/breaker-sometimes-trips-when-microwave-turned-on/167911

Comment: Not a problem I have run into issues because of the difference in curve brands, at my current plant we have 1 load center (MCC) that a mid sized load will flash over and trip a 800 amp main before a 125/150 amp breaker shutting down a segment of the plant but the owners don’t want to spend the $ to convert.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a dedicated breaker? If not, I would recommend 20A - Better to have more than enough - 30A is overkill in most cases.

Comment: It would depend on the wire size than commercial type Refridgeration i have not seen a 20 amp Refrigerator.